# Why would anyone specify font-family: inherit for a button?

Tags: html, css

My CSS specifies font-family: inherit for a button but why is that. I thought with CSS that if you don't specify it will inherit anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common browsers, `button` defaults to a sans-serif font. Specifying `font-family: inherit` overrides that browser default.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes this seems to be the case. Not sure why it does that but you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to override a different setting from a less-specific selector?

```
* {
    font-family: Comic Sans;
}

div {
    font-family: Verdana;
}

button {
     font-family: inherit;  /* look like my parent */
}

<div><button ...></div>
```